# How can I modify a UIElement.property from another class?

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0, winui-3, winui

I'm working on a WinUI app (c# and xaml) with multiple frames and pages.
The problem is that I need to modify a UIElement property (TextBox.Text) from another class. I've been trying so many things and none of them has worked yet.
I'd be glad if someone could inspire me with some useful ways to do it. It can be anything aside from xaml data binding (<property={"Binding bindingName"}).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updating from another class? A class like a ViewModel?

Comment: yes, sort of. In fact I plan to be able to modify from different classes, but from the model is ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally after two weeks of research I've found and check a solution.

The solution is basically rising and catching events from the different classes. I found this information in a MSDN post. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines

This post is REALLY STRAIGHT FORWARD. I've created the CustomEventArgs class and then the publisher class is my controller (.cs) and my subscriber is the model (.xaml.cs).
The only problem that I've encountered is setting alll the methods and attributes as static in order to be able to call the controller function from other models. The problem is that on the `raiseEvent(this, e);` in the publisher class, `this` cannot be static so i've written `null` instead.

Also, I'd like to say that it works extremely fluent and with no lag or delay at all even if I constantly use it.

I hope this helps to everybody encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this sample code, I have 2 pages (`Page1` and `Page2`) and 1 ViewModel (`MainViewModel`). Each page has a `TextBox` that are bound to the same property in the `MainViewModel`.

If you change the text in `Page1`, the text in `Page2` will be changed, and vice versa.

**NuGet packages**

- [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction)
- [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace MultiplePagesSingleViewModel;

public partial class App : Application
{
    private Window? window;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(
            new ServiceCollection()
            // This needs to be Singleton
            .AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
            .BuildServiceProvider());
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.window = new MainWindow();
        this.window.Activate();
    }
}
```

**Page1.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MultiplePagesSingleViewModel.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MultiplePagesSingleViewModel"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Page 1" />
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MultiplePagesSingleViewModel;

public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // This MainViewModel is the same instance that Page2 gets.
        ViewModel = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MultiplePagesSingleViewModel.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MultiplePagesSingleViewModel"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Page 2" />
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MultiplePagesSingleViewModel;

public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This MainViewModel is the same instance that Page1 gets.
        ViewModel = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MultiplePagesSingleViewModel;

// This class needs to be "partial" for CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm will automatically generate
    // a UI-Interactive "SomeText" property for you.
    private string someText = "Default text";
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="MultiplePagesSingleViewModel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MultiplePagesSingleViewModel"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
        <local:Page1 Grid.Column="0" />
        <local:Page2 Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that did not work for me because I'm using the UNO Platform, and it does not usually like the xaml data bindings (as I said in the problem description). So, in order to avoid these problems I was thinking doing it with events, if that is possible.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think that Uno "does not usually like the xaml data bindings". See this [instruction](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/windows-ui-xaml-xbind.html?q=bind). And you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) that the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm targets Uno.

Comment: Thanks, but I've insistently tied this and it dos not work. However I've found myself a solution. I'll answer myself.